# Direct access to the values created by the jQuery autoSuggest plug-in from Delphi 6 using Chromium?

Tags: delphi, dom, autosuggest

I am using the jQuery AutoSuggest plug-in:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

I want to access the values the AutoSuggest plug-in accumulates from my Delphi 6 code.  The problem is in the way the AutoSuggest plug-in stores the accumulated values temporarily until you execute a submit operation.  As far as I can tell it does not provide a direct property to get the accumulated values from it.  Instead it manipulates the DOM tree and creates a hidden text element with an ID that contains a randomly generated numeric suffix (as per the AutoSuggest description web page).  Here's an example:

```
<input type="hidden" class="as-values" name="as_values_067" id="as-values-067" value="robotics,monkeys,">
```

Note the randomly generated suffix for the ID attribute (as-values-067).

To get to the element so I can get the *value* attribute and bring the accumulated values into my Delphi 6 code I am doing a full DOM node tree scan to find the visible node element created by AutoSuggest using the NAME attribute of my original AutoSuggest edit box ("editEvernoteTags"):

Then I extract the numeric suffix from the ID attribute (*67 in the above example*), and then search for the hidden text element using the that value appended to the string "as-values".  This allows me to search for the hidden text element using that ID (*as-values-067* in the above example) with the Chromium getElementById() method.

This is a bit of a mess obviously and I would prefer instead to just grab the accumulated values in a single operation.  Does anyone know how to do this from Delphi code?

Comment: haven't used chromium, but if you can call a javascript method from delphi side, you could use jQuery to grab the value in one go, something like function grabValue() { return $( ".as-values" ).val(); } <= we're selecting the textbox by css class.

Comment: additionally, you could return value and id in one go(if you can call the javascript function "grabValue", as function grabValue() { var obj = $( ".as-values" ); return obj.val() + "|" + obj.id; }, now in your delphi code, you know that everything after "|" is the ID

Comment: @TLama can you call javascript functions?